# How to open default iOS apps from a React Native app?

Tags: react-native, ios9, react-native-ios

I'm creating a React Native app and I'd like to be able to open default apps from it. Specifically:

- Phone.app (clicking on a button in my app and opening iOS modal to call a specific number)
- Apple Maps App (clicking on a button in my app and opening the Apple Maps with routing to specified target destination)

I understand I can open the system maps with

````
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() =>
    Linking.openURL(`geo:${latitude},${longitude}`)}>
  <Text>Open Map</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>```
````

and similarly call `openURL("tel:" + telephone)` for phone number. (I omit error handling in the code snippet purposefully.)

Next, it should be necessary to update `ios/Info.plist` to allow these application query schemes. I tried putting this into it:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>geo</string>
  <string>tel</string>
</array>
```

I'm still getting `EUNSPECIFIED` errors. I guess that maybe I'm not supposed to put the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` keys as `geo` and `tel`. I was, however, unable to find out what should go in there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are using simulator then only web URLs can be tested. Other
   URLs require actual device for testing.
2. `geo` is [android only.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10757)

Comment: Thanks. Turns out one should use HTTP links for Apple Maps. See [Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html)